# backup de dados de conteúdos específicos mysql via java

Tags: java, mysql, backup, mysqldump

Olá, tenho o seguinte método que faz o backup do meu banco de dados:

```
public static void makeBackup() throws IOException{
    String caminho = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\\mysqldump.exe";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(caminho, "--user=root",
            "--password=root", "meuBD", "--result-file="
            + "C:\\Users\\Usuário\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\meuPrograma\\" + "Backup.txt");
    pb.start();
}
```

O problema é: quando eu faço o backup, ele salva o sistema inteiro, inclusive tabelas que não são necessarias, eu quero fazer o backup de determinada tabela, com determinado campo.

O que ocorre: tenho um sistema que trabalha com cartão ponto, ou seja, crio um cartão ponto por dia para cada processo e, pode ser que tenha processos com anos de tempo, ou seja, o cartão ponto vinculado ao processo terá milhares de inserts, e vou fazer com que seja possível colocar isso dentro do sistema (fazer update no bd diretamente do sistema) e, se for fazer do bd inteiro seria demorado, mas se eu salvasse os drops tables em um arquivo e os inserts em outro facilitaria. E de preferência, que eu puder salvar os cartões ponto que estão vinculados a um processo em específico, pois aí, reduz ainda mais o tamanho do backup.

Desde já, agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer o backup de uma tabela específica você tem que passar após o nome do banco o nome da tabela ex:

```
public static void makeBackup() throws IOException{
    String caminho = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\\mysqldump.exe";
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(caminho, "--user=root",
        "--password=root", "meuBD minhaTabela", "--result-file="
        + "C:\\Users\\Usuário\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\meuPrograma\\" + "Backup.txt");
    pb.start();
}
```

Agora se você quiser pegar campos específicos ai eu não conheço forma de fazer através do mysqldump, uma solução para isso seria o  SELECT INTO OUTFILE Ex:

```
  SELECT column_a, column_b, column_a+column_b INTO OUTFILE '~/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM table;
```

Comment: Então, na verdade não é pegar os campos em específico, é pegar os registros que tem determinado dado, vamos dizer, todo processo tem diversos cartões pontos vinculados, e digamos que eu quero todos os cartões pontos que tem o processo de id=3 por exemplo, entende? é um pouco diferente de pegar determinada coluna, mas isso já resume bastante o tempo de processamento de restaurar o backup, se você souber responder essa outra dúvida, agradeço muito!

Comment: Cara neste caso não conheço outra forma, que não seja através do select into outfile com where clause, quando quiser importar os dados utilizar LOAD DATA INFILE 'FILENAME' INTO TABLE TABLENAME', ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html, dessa forma você podê criar seu próprio backup da forma como você desejar. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Agradeço! vou tentar fazer aqui!